# Double event on firefox on keydown event

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why with Firefox when I launch keydown event with space my click event is also launched.

With enter no problem.

```
var eventFunction = function(e) {
  if (content.style.display === 'none' || content.style.display === '') {
    content.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('click');
  eventFunction(e);
  this.removeEventListener('click', eventFunction, false);
}, false);
button.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log('keydown');
  if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    eventFunction(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.removeEventListener('keydown', eventFunction, false);
  }
}, false);
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/korigan/f371vcxx/

Comment: space bar fires click just like enter does.

Comment: @epascarello yes, but `e.preventDefault()` stops that from happening in chrome. Probably need to prevent default on `keypress` as well for firefox or something like that.

Comment: @epascarello chrome doesn't think so. However even if firefox does in that way, I think that key event on the button isn't right idea.

Comment: unrelated to issue, but `this.removeEventListener('keydown', eventFunction, false);` is not going to do anything. That is not going to unbind the event that you are in.

Comment: @Sergey Gultyaev the design pattern of button : https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#button there is interaction with space and enter.

Comment: @epascarello ok about removeEventListener. thx.

Comment: @StevenMouret I meant the logic. Because for use the space key I have to choose it, then click it. Also, according to *epascarello* post, FireFox reacts on each key press as click event.

Comment: In order for that line to work, the event listener would need to be `button.addEventListener('keydown', eventFunction, false);` so yes I am sure.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, the click event is fired when you release the key. Listen for `keyup` to call `preventDefault()` on the second event:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('clicked');
});
button.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.key === ' ' || e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Space or Enter');
  }
});
button.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.key === ' ' || e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Press me</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

`e.stopPropagation();` does that you need. No click firing on key press.